# React onclick for each table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, function, bind

I have some data that I can print them by .map()
like this code

```
tabRow(){
   // CSS style for font Icon 
  const editIcon = {
    color: 'blue',
    fontSize: '1.3em',
    padding: '0 5px',
  };
  const trashIcon = {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: '1.3em',
    padding: '0 5px',
  };
 if(this.state.products instanceof Array){
   return this.state.products.map(function(object, i){
       return(
        <tr key={ i }>
            <td>{ object.id }</td>
            <td>{ object.title }</td>
            <td>{ object.body }</td>
            <td width="200px">
          <Icon name="edit" onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)} style={editIcon}
           className="editIconClass" />
          <Icon name="trash" style={trashIcon} className="trashIconClass" />
        </td>
        </tr>
      )
   })
 }
}
```

I use `tabRow()` in the table body

```
<tbody>
   {this.tabRow()}
</tbody>
```

Also I have simple log in the `handleClick()` and also I bind this code in the constructor `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);` I can see my view but when I click to run function i got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined
    at onClick (app.js:61529)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (app.js:40524)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (app.js:40562)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (app.js:40611)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (app.js:40625)
    at executeDispatch (app.js:40890)
    at executeDispatchesInOrder (app.js:40912)
    at executeDispatchesAndRelease (app.js:41010)
    at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (app.js:41021)
    at forEachAccumulated (app.js:40991)
```

What I should do to fix it?

```
And my App.js file looks like this
require('./bootstrap');
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';


import Master from './components/Master';
import CreateProduct from './components/CreateProduct';
import DisplayProduct from './components/DisplayProduct';
import UpdateProduct from './components/UpdateProduct';


render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
      <Route path="/" component={Master} >
        <Route path="/add-item" component={CreateProduct} />
        <Route path="/display-item" component={DisplayProduct} />
        <Route path="/edit/:id" component={UpdateProduct} />
      </Route>
    </Router>,
        document.getElementById('root'));
```

and my handleClick

```
handleClick(i){
  console.log('Click happened', i);
}
```

Comment: it would be better if you post your entire app.js

Comment: @ShivaSai I update my question

Comment: @NAK.dev i am sorry.. i  meant the compenent where you used your handleClick.. not app.js .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access this directly in the map function, you should bind it. You can do this in more than one way. For example, you can use an arrow function. This should be the code for your case:

```
return this.state.products.map((object, i) => (
     <tr key={ i }>
       ...
     </tr>
   ))
```

You could also add `this` as a second argument for the map function [as described here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Comment: Thanks it works.